# How to programmatically press QML Button?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I am building a dialog in QML. I have some `TextField`, but I'd like that if the user presses <kbd>enter</kbd> (`accepted` signal is emitted), the `id: okButton` is pressed, actually activating it visually for a moment.

I see that the `pressed` property is read only.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make it [`checkable`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-button.html#checkable-prop) for a short duration while you emulate the click with the [`checked`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-button.html#checked-prop) property:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    Timer {
        id: timer
        running: true
        repeat: true
        interval: 100
        onTriggered: {
            button.checked = false;
            button.checkable = false;
        }
    }

    Row {
        TextField {
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter

            onAccepted: {
                button.checkable = true;
                button.checked = true;
                timer.start();
            }
        }

        Button {
            id: button
            text: "Submit"
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        }
    }
}
```

From the documentation for the [`accepted()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-textfield.html#accepted-signal) signal of `TextField`:

> This signal is emitted when the Return or Enter key is pressed.

Answer (score 14):

You can simply call clicked() signal for simulating button press:

```
Keys.onReturnPressed: {
    clicked()
    event.accepted = true
}
```

Comment: I'm back here from a notification and just noticed this. I'd say that this approach won't do what the question asks, which is "activating it visually for a moment." This answer will emit the clicked signal, but I doubt the button's visual state will change at all. I haven't tested that out though..